# how to change the current anchor tag href with the nearest anchor tag url with in specific div in jquery

Tags: jquery

Hii i am trying to change the anchor tag href with class media-url with the nearest anchor tage url which is inside field__item div , but i am getting undefined , please let me know where i am doing wrong .

```
  <div class="media media--blazy media--bundle--image media--image media--responsive is-b-loaded">        <a class="media-url" href="https://examplelist/item.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener nofollow noreferrer">
</a>
</div>

<div class="component-spotlight__inner">         
<header class="component-spotlight__title">
            <h2 class="component-spotlight__title-inner">Group Exercise Programs</h2>
            <h4 class="component-spotlight__eyebrow"></h4>
          </header>
 <div class="component-spotlight__content">
  <div class="field field--name-field-media field--type-link field--label-visually_hidden">
    <div class="image-url field__label visually-hidden">media image url</div>
              <div class="field__item"><a href="https://www.example.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener nofollow noreferrer">https://www.example.com/</a></div>
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>
```

here is my jquery :

```
  let mediaimageurl = $('.media-url').find('.field__item a').attr('href');
  $('.media-url').attr('href' , mediaimageurl);
```

Comment: Define nearest? Do they share a common ancestor?

Comment: @ITgoldman yeah, they do

Comment: What's wrong about using `$(".media-url").closest(".common-ancestor").find(".field__item a")` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use **closest()** to get the parent container and then **next()** to get **.component-spotlight__inner** and finally use **find()** to get the container of your link.

```js
let mediaimageurl = $('.media-url').closest('.media--bundle--image').next('.component-spotlight__inner').find('.field__item a').attr('href');
$('.media-url').attr('href' , mediaimageurl);
console.log(mediaimageurl);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="media media--blazy media--bundle--image media--image media--responsive is-b-loaded">        <a class="media-url" href="https://examplelist/item.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener nofollow noreferrer">
</a>
</div>

<div class="component-spotlight__inner">         
<header class="component-spotlight__title">
            <h2 class="component-spotlight__title-inner">Group Exercise Programs</h2>
            <h4 class="component-spotlight__eyebrow"></h4>
          </header>
 <div class="component-spotlight__content">
  <div class="field field--name-field-media field--type-link field--label-visually_hidden">
    <div class="image-url field__label visually-hidden">media image url</div>
              <div class="field__item"><a href="https://www.example.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener nofollow noreferrer">https://www.example.com/</a></div>
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>
```